# Spark - Return Dataframe and accumulator from function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a function that returns a `DataFrame` and two accumulators. Running manually with `spark-shell` (calling the function from the jar) it works as expected.  Doing a `.count` on the `DataFrame` populates the accumulator.

But if I call the function from `spark-submit` the accumulator always remains empty.
I have tried returning two `DataFrame`'s with the same strange behavior: Works in `spark-shell`, does not from `spark-submit`.

Here is a possibly non functioning skeleton of my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, DataFrame, SQLContext, Row}
import scala.collection._
...

def process(
    sc:SparkContext,
    sqlContext:SQLContext,
    filepaths : RDD[String]
    ): ( 

    val logMetadataAccumulator = sc.accumulableCollection(mutable.ArrayBuffer[( String, String, Long, String, Long, Long)]())
    val logFailedRowAccumulator = sc.accumulableCollection(mutable.ArrayBuffer[( String)]())
    ...
    ...
    val logRecordsPre = logRawFlow.map(
        entry => {
            val date = """(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)""".r
            if ( fields.length == 23 && date.findFirstMatchIn(fields(2)).nonEmpty && fields(22).forall(_.isDigit) && fields(21).forall(_.isDigit) ) {
                ...
                Row( 1L, "blah" "blah", 0L )
            }
            else ( fields(0) == logMetaDataPrefix ) {
                ...
                logMetadataAccumulator += (fileName, logType, numLines, logSource, startTime, endTime)
                Row( 0L, "blah" "blah", 0L )
            }
            else {
                try { 
                    val fileName = fields(0)
                    logFailedRowAccumulator += (fileName)
                    Row( 0L, "blah" "blah", 0L )
                }
                catch {
                    case e: Exception => {
                        logFailedRowAccumulator += ("unknown")
                        Row( 0L, "blah" "blah", 0L )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )

    val logRecords = logRecordsPre.filter( _.getLong(0) != 0L)

    val logDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(logRecords, logSchema)

    ( logDF, logMetadataAccumulator, logFailedRowAccumulator )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad,
 Upon closer inspection I found that whilst manually calling the function in the shell I was doing the `.count` before converting the accumulators to DataFrames, but in the function that saves the Dataframes and is called by the runner from `spark-submit` the dataframe created from the accumulators is created before the returned dataframe has an action on it..

eg:

```
val ( df, acc1, acc2 ) = process( sc, sqlContext, filePaths )
df.count
val acc1Array = acc1.value.toArray
val acc2Array = acc2.value.toArray
```

NOT (What I was doing in the Runner:)

```
val ( df, acc1, acc2 ) = process( sc, sqlContext, filePaths )
val acc1Array = acc1.value.toArray
val acc2Array = acc2.value.toArray
df.count
```